# how to solve openssl configuration error when trying to install react native cli?

Tags: react-native, openssl

When trying to install react native cli I get the following error messages. How can I solve?

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> npm install -g react-native-cli
OpenSSL configuration error:
60210000:error:07000065:configuration file routines:def_load_bio:missing equal sign:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\crypto\conf\conf_def.c:513:HERE-->É$line 1
OpenSSL configuration error:
8C260000:error:07000065:configuration file routines:def_load_bio:missing equal sign:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\crypto\conf\conf_def.c:513:HERE-->É$line 1
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered this exact issue trying to create dynamic openssl config files in powershell. What i learned is that the config file i was creating was encoded with utf-16,  openssl apparently cannot read files with certain encoding. ( even the 3.0 version )

My guess is that just like you the openssl config file being referenced is encoded in utf-16 ( windows default ) and that will never work.  if you open the file in an editor that has encode capability ( i.e. notepad++)  and change its encoding to utf-8 or ANSI and save the file, that error above should disappear.